# Undefinded constant Wiziq::Auth base::HMAC

Tags: canvas-lms, wiziq

I have installed wiziq plugin for web conference via canvas lms made in ruby on rail. When I join the conference I get the error as given below Uninitialize constant Wiziq::Auth base::HMAC
I am not understand where is the problem. Can any body help me to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

WizIq support in Canvas LMS was dropped last November. See link here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/canvas-lms-users/wiziq/canvas-lms-users/Wo1FGCV7DXs/l01MF4pYDwAJ

You can probably bring back wiziq by copying vendor/plugins/wiziq from this release: https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/tree/06dfa7fb6ddeb0fc63a31c723586e620ebbfbe5d/vendor/plugins to your release you are currenty at. I haven't tried this myself so take it with a grain of salt